# Button working in chrome but not in mozilla

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using this html code and this class belongs to bootstrap.css

```
<button class="btn btn-success">
    <a style="color:white;" href="/registration/form">REGISTER</a> 
</button>
```

in chrome on clicking the button it is going to the given link but it is not working in mozilla firefox

Comment: @Dan's answer is right. Putting an a tag within a button tag simply doesn't work in Firefox, but also leads to weird behaviour in other browsers. Specifically, the text itself is the link, but if user hits the button and NOT the text, its gives feedback as if it's working, but does nothing. Use Dan's answer and you're all good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what is causing that, but if you make the `<a>` tag into a button it will fix the issue:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" style="color:white;" href="/registration/form">REGISTER</a>
```

Comment: making chrome so much smart is also very painful